# A variant of Brocard's Problem

Tags: nt.number-theory

[Brocard's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem) asks whether there are any squares of the form $n!+1$ other than $25, 121$ and $5041$. It's not even known whether there are only finitely many squares of this form, although that would follow from the abc conjecture.

I wonder whether extensions of this problem to other polygonal numbers have been looked into, for example:

*Are there any triangular numbers of the form $n!+1$ other than $3$? Are there only finitely many triangular numbers of this form?*